# Is it RESTful to use a HEAD request reveal the existence of a protected resource?

Tags: http, rest, architecture

I have a RESTful resource whose representation should only be retrieved by authenticated clients.  In the case of an unauthenticated client making a GET request, a 401 will be returned.

On the other hand, I want unauthenticated clients to be able to determine if the resource exists.  In this case I am considering having a HEAD request return a 200 if the resource does exist and a 404 if it does not.

RFC 2616 says the following about a HEAD request in Section 9.4

> The metainformation contained in the HTTP headers in response to a HEAD request SHOULD be identical to the information sent in response to a GET request.

Would this approach be considered properly RESTful?

As an alternative, I could have the GET and HEAD requests return 404 for a non existent resource and 401 if the request exists but the client is not entitled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go the 404/401 route. It's much simpler and more orthogonal. And also because the first line of the definition of HEAD reads:

> The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT return a message-body in the response.

And this would leave the way open for HTTP clients that don't support HEAD. Unauthenticated they can simply perform a GET to determine the resource's existence. No HEAD support necessary.

Comment: I think the consensus is pretty clear and the rfc clinches it.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with the latter option (404 for non-existent, 401 for unauthenticated) if you're really going to allow unauthenticated clients to determine the existence of the resource. If that existence information is exposed, 404/401 are the correct responses:

- 404: I'm confirming to you, the unauthenticated client, this resource does not exist.
- 401: I reject your request because you do not have the appropriate authorization to obtain this resource.

Plus, this allows an authenticated client to HEAD the resource for a 200 if they have the appropriate access and it exists.